# RQ: success and failure handling when using `@job` decorator

Tags: python, rq

I am using `@job` decorator to define a task as below:

```py
rqueue = Queue(connection=Redis.from_url(REDIS_URL))

@job(queue=rqueue)
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(2)
    return x+y
```

this works fine when I call it like `add.delay(100, 100)`. But I need to provide success and callback handler for my job. When I define my job as `@job(queue=rqueue, on_success=my_callback_func)` it fails with a message saying that it got an unexpected keyword argument `on_success`.

If I enqueue the job like below it works smoothly:

```py
rqueue.enqueue(add, on_success=my_callback_func)
```

I also tried passing the callback handler with `delay` function but no luck.

Please Help !!!